# Polymer Dart package layout conventions?

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I'm currently working on a project which contains a number of components (polymer elements). All said and done, I'll probably be looking at around 10+ components for the application. At the moment, following Pub's [Package Layout Conventions](http://pub.dartlang.org/doc/package-layout.html) each .html and associated .dart file is in the web/ directory.

It would be nice to have them in lib/src/ of my application and only have the main files in web/ however at the moment `<link ref="import" href="package:my_app/src/my_component.html">` will not work (See [Issue 12867](http://dartbug.com/12867)).

Are there currently any conventions in use to handle multiple (private) components for an app? Should I create a web/src/ directory to load imports/source files relative to the web/ directory? Would it even make sense to keep Polymer Element .html files in lib/src/ (assuming it was supported) as they're not pure dart files as traditionally recommended/expected in a pub package layout?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, package: works only for external components (dependencies declared in pubspec.yaml), and the default path is the packages folder (created by pub install). See the getting started section here: [Dart Pub](http://pub.dartlang.org/doc/)

I keep components in their own folders under the web directory so web/component1, web/component2 and so on and I use relative links to import across components. Not sure if this is the best practice but it works.

Comment: Package also works for internal components of your own package as well, used in directories like bin, or web, and will link to your own package's lib/ director. See: http://pub.dartlang.org/doc/package-layout.html#implementation-files However the referenced bug prevents it from working in html files. See bug for this question: http://dartbug.com/13991